# Unlock PDF and Display in UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf

So I need to download PDFs that are password protected, unlock them, and then display them via the UIDocumentInteractionController. So far, I'm downloading the password protected PDFs and found out how to unlock a PDF using the CG framework (CGPDFDocumentRef) but I can't figure out how to get the unlocked document back as an NSData from CG. Plus I'm not sure how to pass UIDocumentInteractionController an NSData object. If anyone has done this before, please help.

Comment: Why do you want an `NSData` object? The `UIDocumentController` takes a URL to the file you want it to display.

Comment: Well I didn't want to save an unlocked version of the PDF to disc. After unlocking a CGPDFDocumentRef with CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword() I end up with an NSData object containing the unlocked PDF. I just want to display the PDF rather than save the NSData to disc and then have UIDocumentInteractionController read it. It's a security thing.

Comment: Hi enamrik!! How do you converted the CGPDFDocumentRef to NSData??

Comment: If you unlock a pdf use CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword ,it just return a CGPDFDocumentRef.
How could you save it to disc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. UIDocumentInteractionController only works with NSURL objects and there is no way to pass UIDocumentInteractionController in-memory data. Since I didn't want to spend any more time on this, I decided to instead, each time a user taps the document, to decrypt the PDF, save it to disc and then pass UIDocumentInteractionController the path to the temp file (temp file must exist on disc while UIDocumentInteractionController is open). I'll probably have to role my own PDF viewer if this doesn't fly with the client's security requirements.

Comment: aim having this same issue, as i don't want save decrypted files to disk... did you made any progress on this?

Comment: Another iOS wish bites the dust.